# How can I install Windows on two separate disks separately?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, uefi, windows-11, windows-installation

I want to have two separate Windows installations on two separate disks on my PC (with Secure Boot enabled). The first installation succeeds and works fine, but when I try to install another Windows on a second disk, the very first reboot during installation does not work (it boots from the wrong partition/disk).

Trying to boot to the correct partition/disk *manually* fails, as BIOS/UEFI does not show the second disk as a boot option.

How can I install Windows separately on two disks, so that I can boot from one or the other in BIOS/UEFI boot menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: As soon as Windows sees a bootable disk, it does not create another for the second Windows installation.

To work around this problem, disconnect the first disk for the time of the installation on the second disk. You do not have to do this physically, if your BIOS/UEFI offers you the possibiltiy to disable single SATA/M2 ports.

After installation of the second disk, you can re-plug the first disk. You will then have two separate bootable disks.